# cross-browser way to get contenteditable's content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, contenteditable

Different browsers generate the elements inside `contenteditable` differently. It's especially obvious when you have line breaks, or paste multi-line stuffs in.

In the old days with `textarea`, you can simply do `$('textarea').val()` to retrieve the content inside, and it's reliable and cross-browser compatible.

I wonder is there such **universally-agreed** method to retrieve content inside a `contenteditble` as well, such that it's striped off html tags, and lines are properly separated by `\n`. If not, how does Facebook messenger do it reliably? Do you need a complicated algorithm with browser detection?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be this:

```
 var content = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]').textContent
```

The jury's still out on whether it's *universally agreed* upon because you would probably have to account for differences between browsers regarding newlines and what not.

Comment: I tried building an application using contenteditable and had to give up and go back to the drawing board because of how different browsers added different html tags and there's no easy cross-browser way to get just the content...